# How to move a UIImageView towards a certain point based on its degrees rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a **rocket** UIImageView that constantly rotates around itself with an NSTimer:

```
 rotationDegrees = rotationDegrees + 0.5
 rocket.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationDegrees * CGFloat(M_PI/180) )
```

Once I tap on the screen, I need it to simply fire it into a specific trajectory (I'm using UIKit, no SpriteKit, so please no SpriteKit suggestions :)
Here's a picture as an example of trajectory:

[image]

My touchesBegan() method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // Invalidate the timer that rotates the Rocket
        rotationTimer.invalidate()
    
        // Fire timer that moves the Rocket
        moveRocketTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "moveRocket", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Here's the function where I need to move the Rocket like 8 points X and 8 points Y

```
func moveRocket() {
  rocket.center.x = ??? + 8
  rocket.center.y = ??? + 8
}
```

I'm using a NSTimer to move the rocket because I need to check its collision with another view by using **if CGRectIntersectsRect()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use trigonometry to calculate the change in x & y for a given angle:

```
y = sin(angle);
x = cos(angle);
```

That will give you values that range from -1 to 1. You'll need to scale them as desired (In your question you multiply by 8.

Your angle values need to be in radians. So if your angle is in degrees, you might want to write a function to convert degrees to radians:

```
func radiansFromDegrees(degrees: Float) -> Float
{
  return degrees * M_PI/180;
}
```

And if you want your ship to move 8 points / frame then you should multiply by 8. So that would give you:

```
rocket.center.y += 8.0 * sin(radiansFromDegrees(angle));
rocket.center.x += 8.0 * cos(radiansFromDegrees(angle));
```

You'll probably have to do some type-casting to make the compiler happy, since I think sin and cos return doubles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! do you mean something like this:     rocket.center.x = cos(rotationDegrees) * 8  --  rocket.center.y = sin(rotationDegrees) * 8 ? May you please write an example for my moveRocket() function? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea, but you need to convert the angles to radians. Why don't you write the code yourself and post back if you can't make it work. You'll learn a lot more if I don't give you code you can simply drop into place.

Comment: Ok, I was looking for a quick solution, I'm not experienced with radians and degrees at all. Thanks anyway, but I hope someone will post a better answer, I can't accept yours, sorry :(

Comment: So the only answer you'll accept is somebody writing your code for you? You don't belong on SO then. Computer graphics requires a working knowledge of trig and algebra. The code you posted already has code to convert degrees to radians. Think for yourself!

Comment: Well, have you ever seen somebody posting a code that users ASK for? I did, lots of times around here, otherwise why should users make questions, if the answer they get is approximate, or incomplete, or it basically says: do it yourself, buddy, here's a couple of variables, now figure it out on your own. Maybe a couple of example lines of code from you would have been great for your resume as well, for new users who'll land here, not a bad idea :)

Comment: I gave you a couple of lines of code. It's obvious from your comment about not understanding radians, even though the code that you posted includes a degrees-to-radians conversion, that you have no idea what you are doing and would just copy/paste any code I gave you. That's a "give a man a fish" solution rather than a "teach a man to fish" solution. I'm interested in teaching you how to do things for yourself, not giving you code that you paste without understanding it. Show some effort if you want help.

Comment: I understand, what you could have done was posting some sample code with an explanation, comments, not just a code to copy/paste, that's how we experienced that users learn something new. just comment the code you write, like any tutorial around the web. Anyway, I'll accept this answer, at least i could use your lines of code to search for other answers here and learn the conversion from degrees to radians. Thanks.